# Powershell get-members of $EventArgs automatic variable

Tags: powershell, events

I want to list all available properties of the variable `$EventArgs` by piping it to `get-member`. but I am having trouble to get the members of the automatic variable `$EventArgs`.

In the example I can see that they get the property. FullPath from the automatic variable $EventArgs. I want a way to list all the properties that maybe are useful.

Any ideas of how to get the members of $EventArgs automatic variable.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$watcher.Site
$arrary = @()

$watcher.Filter = ""
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
   write-host "Created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
  $arrary+= $EventArgs|gm
  $arrary+= $EventArgs
  write-host $EventArgs|gm
  $EventArgs|gm
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to see all of the properties (there are only three) is to do this:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
    $eventArgs | Select-Object * | Write-Host
}
```

However, you'll get much more useful information if you do this:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
    Write-Host $eventArgs.GetType()
}
```

and then look up the resultant type on MSDN.  When you do that, you'll see that `$EventArgs` is actually an object of type `System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs`, which is [fully documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Not only will you see the three properties, you'll see what they mean.  For example, the first property `ChangeType` is really an enumeration of the type `System.IO.WatcherFileTypes`, and you can learn all of the different values it can have.